# Converting data into image is sending nil, when I am fetching images from google drive in iOS app

Tags: ios, image, google-drive-api

I am using following code to fetch image from google drive. It is giving me correct meta data about files.But in completion handler the data is of image which on conversion giving nil.

**Code:**

```
    if let files = response.files where !files.isEmpty {
        filesString += "Files:\n"
        for file in files as! [GTLDriveFile] {
            filesString += "\(file.name) (\(file.identifier))\n"
            let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(file.identifier)"//?alt=media"
            let fetcher =  service.fetcherService.fetcherWithURLString(url)
             fetcher.beginFetchWithCompletionHandler({ (tempData :NSData?, error : NSError?) in
                if error == nil
                {
                   // image is nil .
                    if let image = UIImage(data:tempData!,scale:1.0)
                                     {

                                    }  
                }
                else
                {
                print("error")

                }

            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding "?alt=media" to url.

**Code:**

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/\(file.identifier)?alt=media"
```

And then you can use data.